# How to show DateTimePicker control on messagebox using c#?

Tags: c#, windows, datetime

Is it possible to show DateTimePicker control on messagebox to select date in Console applciation.

Comment: Couldn't you add a modal form?

Answer (score 1):

Not on a standard MessageBox.  You need to create your own form to display.

Comment: I am using console application not windows application

Comment: @KiranReddy Then you should use console input to have the user enter a date.

Answer (score 0):

```
`public MyClass()
 {
 // Create a new DateTimePicker
 DateTimePicker dateTimePicker1 = new DateTimePicker();

 Controls.AddRange(new Control[] {dateTimePicker1});
 MessageBox.Show(dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString());

 dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
 MessageBox.Show(dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString());
 }
```

`

This a method to access the date picker control in your message box.

What have you done exactly? Can you explain the requirement a little more elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

`MessageBox` is a convenient function. That convenience comes at the cost of customization. `MessageBox` does not provide a way to add your own controls to it; you must create your own form.

Note that even in console applications you can still create windows forms.

Answer (score 0):

I know its late but if someone is looking how to do it. Use CustomMessageBox insetead of MessageBox. Tutorial can be found [Here](http://windowsapptutorials.com/windows-phone/general/how-to-create-a-custom-messagebox-in-windows-phone-application-3/)

```
TimePicker timePicker = new TimePicker()
                {
                    Margin = new Thickness(0, 10, 0, 10)
                }; 

                StackPanel myStackPanel = new StackPanel();
                myStackPanel.Orientation = System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Vertical;
                myStackPanel.Children.Add(timePicker);                    

                //Create a new custom message box
                CustomMessageBox messageBox = new CustomMessageBox()
                {
                    Content = myStackPanel,
                    LeftButtonContent = "Ok",
                    RightButtonContent = "Cancel",                        
                    IsFullScreen = false                        
                };

                messageBox.Show();
```